# Treeview: custom order after adding new root nodes

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I have 10 different root nodes that I don't want to add untill I need them (They doesn't exist, as long as I won't call them). So I used

```
treeView1.Nodes.Insert(0, Node);
treeView1.Nodes.Insert(1, Node);
treeView1.Nodes.Insert(2, Node);
```

And so on. If I'll add Node0, Node1 and Node2 everything works fine. But if I'll try to change order like Node2, Node1, Node0, I experience problem - Node0 works fine, but there's no Node1, but two Node2 or Node1 and Node2 switch places. Is it possible to skip some position, to use it in future? To check Node index I used this code, attached to button:

```
MessageBox.Show(treeView1.SelectedNode.Index.ToString());
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are using the wrong method to add nodes.

For the initial creation you can just use `treeView1.Nodes.Add(node)`. 
When you actually want to insert a node at a given index, work out where you want it and then use `Insert` at the appropriate index.

The reason your nodes are swapping places is because in the example above the insert is meaningless. Inserting a node in position 2 in a list with no nodes will add it at position 0 instead.

EDIT: Adding code sample.

```
        TreeNode node1 = new TreeNode("Node 1");

        view.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode("Node 0"));
        view.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode("Node 2"));
        view.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode("Node 4"));

        // Point 1

        view.Nodes.Insert(1, node1);

        // Point 2

        view.Nodes.Insert(3, new TreeNode("Node 3"));

        // Point 3
```

At Point 1 your collection of nodes would be
Node 0
Node 2
Node 4

At Point 2 your collection of nodes would be
Node 0
Node 1
Node 2
Node 4

At Point 3 your collection of Nodes would be
Node 0
Node 1
Node 2
Node 3
Node 4

Comment: Could you be more specific? I guess that I can't use .Add and .Insert at the same time, it will cause errors.

Comment: Be more specific about what, exactly?

Comment: Is that possible to use Insert on existing node? Or do you mean to change selected node and after that use Insert?  Sorry for that kind of questions, I'm kinda newbie.

Comment: Thanks for clearing it out, although my problem is not solved. I've got 10 nodes and none of them is present at the beggining, so I guess I must start with Insert, because you never know which one will go first, second, etc. Is that possible to create custom sorting? Because if I'm trying to add Node4 first, it gets 0 index anyway.

Comment: Until you post some code Im afraid I cant help you any more. Ive explained what your initial problem with ordering  was (ie, you were inserting at meaningless Indexes).